# Support for Hard and Soft Deletes in Amazon Kendra

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kendra

Does Amazon Kendra support both Soft and Hard Delete?
Want flexibility to flag a document as deleted rather than completely removing the record. I'm aware of APIs that will perform hard delete (BatchDelete) but didn't come across any for Soft delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendra currently supports only BatchDelete (hard delete).